# Tips on running Processing on server - best server, how to run

Tags: processing

I would like to run a Processing script.pde file on a server because it's too much for my laptop.  I do not have my own server currently, so was thinking of purchasing some space on an Amazon cloud server. Does anyone have recommendations on how to do this, or alternative workflows?

I was planning to use Ubuntu and follow the steps in the following link

https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Running-without-a-Display

Comment: This kind of feels like you're making Processing do something it was never meant for, like number crunching. What does your "script.pde" do?

Comment: It just draws a simple picture.  My problem is that it's hard on my computer, with the graphical display and such. (When framerate is high, eg, 400 it goes fast, but very expensive.)  So I hoped to run it somewhere else.  Unless there is another way to run to use fewer resources - would appreciate any tips!

Comment: Why would a picture require a framerame? If you need single figures, remember to use `noLoop()`?

Comment: It is a random walk - so it generates an image based on eg 10,000 itérations of a random walk.

Comment: Sorry I had commented that after but it didn’t go through.  If there is some way to eg take 1000 iterations between frames that would be nice.  But probably that’s not possible.  I think the refresh at each frame is what’s expensive.  If I lower drawer are to eg 10, it’s not so bad, but takes very long to run.

Comment: random walking takes no time, and 10,000 random walks still takes no time. Nor does it require running an animation loop: set `noLoop()`, compute your 10,000 steps, then draw the single picture? Without any code it's impossible to tell why this would take so long you're trying to offload it.

Comment: What are "frames"? What are you _actually doing in this code_ and can you maybe _show_ your code?

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer to noloop!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210956/discussion-between-user0-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).